# how to remove an item and subitem from a listview and a text file

Tags: c#, listview

I currently have my code save text from a two text boxes to a text file and load it in the listview. how would i if i pressed a button get it to remove not only the item from the listview but from the text file as well so it won't load it the next time i open the program?

my current code for saving is

```
    private void btnAddxuid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.Text = txtxuidGamertag.Text;
            lvi.SubItems.Add(txtXuid.Text);
            listXuid.Items.Add(lvi);
            TextWriter xuids = new StreamWriter(xuidspath, true);
            xuids.WriteLine(txtxuidGamertag.Text + "-" + txtXuid.Text);
            txtXuid.Clear();
            txtxuidGamertag.Clear();
            xuids.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does each item's index belongs to the line in the file with the same line-number?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter I don't know how I would do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution (without reworking your overall approach) would be to simply attach to the OnClick even of a remove button. The handler would then decide which item to remove (i'll assume the 'selected' one), remove it then write over the file with the current contents of the listview.

Example (note, this is pseudo-code)

```
OnRemoveButtonClickHandler()
{
    listXuid.Items.Remove(listXuid.SelectedItem);

    // open the file for overwriting
    foreach (var item in listXuid.Items)
    {
        // write out each item in your format
    }
}
```

In general, you should try to keep the 'data and logic' in your application away from your user interface. In this case, that would mean writing a model class for elements in the list, binding the list items source to a collection of those items then dealing with the backing file source when needed (i.e, load the data-structure at startup and write to it only when you need to). The presentation would be handled by some kind of data template.

If you're interested, check out WPF and MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

the best idea is to save and re-write all of your items on the text file ONLY when you exit the program, or when your program throws an unhandled exception. so you don't need to access the file every time you click the delete or add buttons. hope you get the idea...